# How to fix the out of page text issue in equation mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, width

[image]

I am trying to write the text in equation mode but the text is going out of a page. The code of my equations is given below.
Can anybody help to fix the issue?

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
P\geq 1-\in  \hspace{8cm} \textrm{Random Selection} \\ (P\geq(1-\in)/2)\& (P<1-\in)\&(OP\ne 0) \hspace{1cm} \textrm { Select a neighbor havinng highest value of $(Q_{value}*PELT)$}\\
(P\geq(1-\in)/2)\&(p<1-\in)\&(QP=0) \hspace{5cm}  \textrm {Random Selection}\\
(P<(1-\in)/2)\& (W_{max=0}) \hspace{7cm} \textrm {Random Selection} \\
(P<(1-\in)/2)\&(W_{max}\ne 0) \hspace{2cm} \textrm {Select a neighbor based on highest composed weight}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: please always post complete small documents that show the problem, you have given no indication of the page size so we can not see what fits and what does not. Use of explicit lengths such as `\hspace{8cm}` is almost always wrong though.

Comment: unrelated but `\in` is intended for set inclusion is `1-\in` intended or is that intended to be `\epsilon` (or `\varepsilon`) ?

Comment: @David Carlisle I have added pic as well 
As you can see the equation # "3.45" is borderline of the page but my text is going out of a page

Comment: you can't debug a picture either, please always make examples a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` although your picture shows again that you are using math italic for words, the math italic font is designed to separate letters to be a product of variables which is why `$NELT_{max}$` looks ureadable, it should be `$\mathrm{NELT}_{\max}$`

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a test file so I supplied one this time, assuming US Letter page size and 10pt fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill text\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill text\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
P\geq 1-\in  \hspace{8cm} \textrm{Random Selection} \\
(P\geq(1-\in)/2)\& (P<1-\in)\&(OP\ne 0) \hspace{1cm} \textrm { Select a neighbor havinng highest value of $(Q_{value}*PELT)$}\\
(P\geq(1-\in)/2)\&(p<1-\in)\&(QP=0) \hspace{5cm}  \textrm {Random Selection}\\
(P<(1-\in)/2)\& (W_{max=0}) \hspace{7cm} \textrm {Random Selection} \\
(P<(1-\in)/2)\&(W_{max}\ne 0) \hspace{2cm} \textrm {Select a neighbor based on highest composed weight}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
$NELL_{max}$is the \ldots

\noindent X\dotfill text\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
P\geq 1-\epsilon  &
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright Random Selection} \\
(P\geq(1-\epsilon)/2)\& (P<1-\epsilon)\&(QP\ne 0) &
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright Select a neighbor having highest value of $(Q_{\mathrm{value}}*\mathrm{PELT})$}\\
(P\geq(1-\epsilon)/2)\&(P<1-\epsilon)\&(QP=0) &
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright Random Selection}\\
(P<(1-\epsilon)/2)\& (W_{\max=0}) &
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright Random Selection} \\
(P<(1-\epsilon)/2)\&(W_{\max\ne 0}) &
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright Select a neighbor based on highest composed weight}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$\mathrm{NELL}_{\max}$is the \ldots


\noindent X\dotfill text\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Note that `array` is designed for arrays and matrices of values, not multi-line displays, it sets its entries in text mode, not display mode. Also multi-letter identofiers should be set using `\mathrm` or `\mathit` as the default math italic font is designed to separate adjacent letters so they appear as a product of variables, not as a word.

I also adjusted several other things that I suspected to be typos `\in` to `\epsilon`, p to P, `_{max} \neq 0` to `_{\max \neq 0}` etc.

Comment: oh actually I probably changed that the wrong way I suspect it should be `Q_{\max} = 0` (and same with `\neq` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposal so very long lines are avoided in both columns.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\AND}{\mathrel{\&}}
\newcommand{\LC}[1]{%
  $\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{array}$%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\displaywidth}{@{}l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\LC{P\geq 1-\varepsilon} & Random Selection
\\
\addlinespace
\LC{
  (P\geq(1-\varepsilon)/2) \AND \\
  \quad (P<1-\varepsilon) \AND (\mathit{OP}\ne 0)
} &
Select a neighbor having highest value of $(Q_{\mathrm{value}}\cdot\mathit{PELT})$
\\
\addlinespace
\LC{
  (P\geq(1-\varepsilon)/2) \AND \\
  \quad (p<1-\varepsilon) \AND (\mathit{QP}=0)
} &
Random Selection
\\
\addlinespace
\LC{
  (P<(1-\varepsilon)/2) \AND (W_{\max}=0)
} &
Random Selection
\\
\addlinespace
\LC{
  (P<(1-\varepsilon)/2) \AND (W_{\max}\ne 0)
} &
Select a neighbor based on highest composed weight
\end{tabularx}
\right.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

The macro `\LC` (left column) uses math mode and builds an `array`; the right column is typeset in text mode and its width is automatically computed.

Note the changes I made, notably `\varepsilon` for `\in` (you might prefer `\epsilon`, I don't); also multiletter identifiers are inside `\mathit` so the spacing between the letters is less than it would be with standard math italic; textual subscripts are typeset upright. The command `\AND` produces an ampersand with the right spacing for a binary relation.

[image]